# Regex to substitute character with numbers around it in filenames with rename utility (perl based)

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, perl

I would like to rename files that have the following format:

`somethingblabla15T06:58_31+0000somethingblabla.bla`

THe new name should be

`somethingblabla15T06:58:31+0000somethingblabla.bla`

So the `_` within the numbers should be replaced with `:`.

I would like to do this with the perl based rename command line tool.

I thought this would be a part of the regex:

`'s/[0-9](_)[0-9]/:'`

I can't get it to work. I think this should also be escaped or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
rename 's/([0-9])_([0-9])/$1:$2/'
```

#### Example

Consider a directory with this file:

```
$ ls som*
somethingblabla15T06:58_31+0000somethingblabla.bla
```

Let's run `rename` and then run `ls` again:

```
$ rename 's/([0-9])_([0-9])/$1:$2/' s*
$ ls som*
somethingblabla15T06:58:31+0000somethingblabla.bla
```

#### How it works

`([0-9])_([0-9])` matches a digit followed by an underscore followed by a digit.  Because of the parens, each digit is saved in a group.  The replacement text is `$1:$2` where `$1` refers to the first saved group and `$2` to the second saved group.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do the job without capture groups:

```
rename 's/(?<=\d)_(?=\d)/:/' something*
```

**Explanation:**

```
s/              # substitute
    (?<=\d)       # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a digit before
    _             # underscore
    (?=\d)        # positive lookahead, make sure we have a digit after
/               # with
    :             # colon
/               # end subst.
```